# AdMob rewarded video ad shows impressions, but no earnings, what is it?

Tags: admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

See the problem that is happening: the user can watch award-winning ads to unlock a premium feature in the app. It turns out that several award-winning videos have been watched, users are earning the premium feature, but on the AdMob panel, the rewarded video always appears $ 0.00, it is the only ad unit that never appears to win. That month there were 87 impressions, and $ 0.00 in earnings. Is currently being loaded for users and is not configured as testDevice.

Note: I am not using the latest version of the admob sdk, because when I put the dependency on the latest version there are several errors with other dependencies that I was unable to correct, because the latest version of admob is from androidx, and I don't use androidx. When I tried to switch to androidx, my entire application got errors.

My question is: since Google Admob doesn’t want to generate earnings for me with the rewarded video and is getting 100% of the profits from this ad, **I can exchange the rewarded video ad for an interstitial ad and unlock the prize only if the user clicks in the interstitial ad?** This would be prompted to the user.

**Edit: I managed to update the project for androidx and the dependence of admob for the latest version, and after a while, I see that it still doesn't give any revenue.**

In this post there are several people talking who have the same problem and no answer was given: https://support.google.com/admob/thread/1873844?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, but with Interstitial ads. If you implemented a rewarded video, then stay with it over the Interstitial ad, since Admob doesn't count as legitimate impression if a closes the interstitial ad with a back button. With a rewarded ad, you can at least know when the ad was legitimately closed and generate an ad token. Point is to avoid Admob Interstitial ads and to use rewarded ad instead.

If that doesn't work, then go with Mopub. I feel that Admob is stealing revenue from the developer, especially on interstitial ad.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay. To date, Rewarded Video ads are not generating revenue, and neither are Interstitial ads. Only banner ads are generating revenue in my app, and generating very little. I invited a friend to take a test and he stayed in the app all night watching a banner ad. He didn't give a cent. But there should be no problems with them, since some days I earn something like $ 0.03. Users see advertisers, brands, stores, and I don't gain anything from it, it's not fair.

Comment: I now got more data and more users as my app grew bigger since I posted. The revenue varies wildly from day to day. Yesterday, I got "CA$0.02/CA$0.00/44/38/88.64%/CA$0.02" (Est. earnings/Requests/Impr./Match rate/eCPM), from which 2/5 countries have paid me. Today, I got "CA$0.07/17/12/94.12%/CA$5.69" from 1/3 countries only because the user clicked on the ads. I agree that it's not fair when advertisers get free views from our app. The only solution is to work with advertisers and sponsors directly when you're popular enough (over 1 million downloads).

Comment: You get paid if someone CLICKS on your ad. That happens on average every 100 times (very rough estimate). So if you have 50 impressions doesnt mean you get paid if noone clicked your ads. Thats why some apps like to TAILER ads so they are more relevant and users click them more.

Answer (score 0):

You get paid if someone **clicks** on your ad, **not** for impressions.

If you have very little impressions, its likely that not a single person clicked on your ad generating you a whole 0.00$.

Thats why some apps like to TAILER ads so they are more relevant and users click them more.

Answer (score 0):

The way you get paid the most is if someone clicks your ads.
If people only watch the ad without clicking it you can get paid **as little as 1 Cent for 2000 impressions (according to Google)**

By the way, prompting users to click on your ads (as you were thinking with the interstitial ads) is considered fraud and your account will get terminated if you do this.